# How can I test an expected 404 response on a private resource page out of production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where users are authors of objects called "Binders". This is a private resource where one user shouldn't be able to view the binder of another user unless it is being shared. I would like my application to 404 whenever a user tries to do such a thing. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
class BindersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_access, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  private
    def authenticate_access
      if current_user != @binder.user
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { head :missing }
          format.json { head :missing }
        end
      end
    end
end
```

My problem is that Rails prefers to 500 in development and test. This makes this impossible to check with a test like the following.

```
class BindersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    @alices_binder = binders(:alices_binder)
    @alice = users(:alice)
    @eve = users(:eve)
  end

  teardown do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  test 'binders#show should be missing if accessed by wrong user'
    login_as @eve, scope: :user
    get binder_url(@alices_binder)
    assert_response :missing
  end
end
```

How can I properly test this behavior out of production?

Comment: change `head :missing` by `head :not_found`

Comment: on a side note, the correct error code that you should be using in those cases is `403 Forbidden`